# Adding ubuntu iscsi disk to windows failover cluster

Tags: storage, windows-server-2016, iscsi, failovercluster, ubuntu-18.04

I did this previously with a server on ubuntu 16.04 and targetcli. It worked and is still online today. I'm in need of more storage so I decided to make another machine with ubuntu 18.04 and targetcli-fb. The problem I have is that I cannot add the server to the failover cluster.

When I add the disk to the cluster it says the disk is not ready.
On the event log of the cluster it gives IDs : 1793, 1069, 1205 and 1254
When I use the validation assistant it fails the "Validate SCSI-3 Persistent Reservation", something about "REGISTER AND IGNORE EXISTING" failing.

I do not remember what was done with the previous storage server and cannot remember if there was a configuration to make the disk able to go offline on one node if another brought it online as it asks to be done.

Disk is currently offline on all nodes, partition style is GPT and really should be able to connect, but it just does not.

Comment: When you created the backstore in targetcli, did you do it with IBLOCK or PSCSI?  If it's PSCSI, perhaps the underlying device is a SATA disk or NVME, and doesn't support SCSI reservations?  IBLOCK will terminate the reservation inside the target, so it works regardless of the backing hardware.

Comment: I created a iblock.

Comment: Wow, perhaps @BaronSamedi1958 is correct?  You could check `dmesg` on the server to see if there's anything interesting, or grab a packet capture and see what's being returned.  But, perhaps it'd be easier to just start again with 16.04?  Crazy!

Comment: I'm most likely going to go back to 16.04 for now, I really don't understand why it would not work on 18.04, or maybe I'll try again later, maybe I did something worng...

Answer (score 1):

Replace (upgrade) your iSCSI target, within the current configuration it doesn’t support “persistent reservations”, and this is a “no go” for Windows cluster storage.

Comment: Replace to something else then targetcli-fb or go back to 16.04 for it to work ?

Comment: 1) Upgrade LIO within current distro 2) Use SCST from here -> http://scst.sourceforge.net 3) Roll back to working Linux distro 4) Use StarWind Free on top of free Hyper-V Server 5) ...